# Confusion by the usage of indent-tabs-mode nil

Tags: indentation

I use `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` in my init file so to avoid using TABs but when I write some files (like C++ files) then it allows me to insert TABs if I am in an if-statement for example. Why is that happening?

Also I thought initially that `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` prevents the usage of TABs completely but I have seen in a lot of answers that it converts TABs to spaces. How is it doing that?

Answer (score 5):

Major modes and minor modes are allowed to locally change the `indent-tabs-mode` variable, and a lot of them do. That's why `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` might not always be enough.

This is what I use.

```
(defun endless/c-hook ()
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook #'endless/c-hook)
```

Comment: This is layer/major-mode specific... I face the issue of not having an appropriate hook for `shell-scripts` mode to override the `indent-tabs-mode`. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you are asking. Non-`nil` `indent-tabs-mode` means that Emacs can use `TAB` chars instead of a number of consecutive `SPC` chars.  If the value is `nil` in a given buffer then indentation by Emacs (e.g. automatic indentation) uses only `SPC` chars.  But even in that case there is nothing preventing you from inserting a `TAB` char (e.g., using `C-q TAB`).

What `setq-default` does determines only the default behavior.  In any given buffer (e.g., in any given mode), the value can be different from the default (aka global) value.  It is the buffer-local value that determines the behavior (as described in the previous paragraph).

"Conversion" of `TAB` chars to one or more consecutive `SPC` chars happens if `indent-tabs-mode` is `nil` and you hit `DEL` (the Backspace key) or you change the code in such a way that the appropriate indentation column changes.  All that happens is that if a `TAB` char needs to be removed to meet the new indentation level then `SPC` chars replace it as needed.  Existing `TAB` chars that do not need to be removed to get proper indentation are not removed.

---

(On a different but related subject, be aware that you can replace all existing `TAB` chars in a buffer by doing `C-x h M-x untabify`.)

Comment: What I am asking is why am I allowed to use TABS in some files when I have `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` in my init file. Not by pressing `C-q TAB` but just TAB. Also does that by default converts TABs to spaces?

Comment: Adam: Check the *actual* value for any given buffer with `C-h v indent-tabs-mode` -- that will at least tell you whether it has the value you thought it had. As Drew points out, any mode (or other elisp) is free to override the default value that you've set.

Comment: Also note that `indent-tabs-mode` *doesn't* govern whether or not the buffer may contain tabs, and changing the value has no immediate automatic effect on the buffer contents. The value only affects what happens to the affected line(s) when Emacs *performs* an indentation action.

Comment: See also `C-h v backward-delete-char-untabify` regarding the conversion of tabs to spaces when deleting indentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is in addition to [Malabarba's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/50/malabarba) [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12217/15021).

I had this same issue.  I realized that the indent-tabs-mode value was being persisted in each buffer.

If you have the problem and can't resolve it, make sure to regenerate your buffers (kill buffer and re-open files).  I am new to emacs, so there probably is a better solution, but this worked for me.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: True, but you must have a higher reputation in order to comment on other's answers.  This was the only alternative I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

`(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)` in `c++-mode-hook`

Comment: Please consider extending your answer a bit. As it stands, it does not fully address OPs question(s).