# Confusion about space and tab characters in Emacs

Tags: indentation, whitespace, tabs

I am confused by space (`SPC`) and `TAB` characters in Emacs.

I am often using the default fundamental mode.

When I select a region and indent the lines in the region by `C-u 9 C-x TAB`, I intend to indent the lines by 9 `SPC` characters.

But after I perform the operation, when I place my cursor at the beginning at such a line, and type right arrow key, it jumps to the 8th position with the 9th position also blank, as if there were a `TAB` character followed by a `SPC` character.  This is contrary to my intention to indent the lines by 9 `SPC` characters.

I was wondering how to understand the uses and display of `SPC` and `TAB` characters in Emacs? Is there some general principles that I can follow to understand?

Btw, I may have asked similar question about the confusion between `SPC` and `TAB` characters in Emacs before, either here or Unix.SE or SO. But I can't find it.

Comment: There is no standard way to display a tab character. By default, Emacs uses both tab and space characters for indentation. You can choose to use only space characters by setting the default or buffer-local value of `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil`.

Comment: Mixed spaces and tabs are one of a number of poor legacy defaults in Emacs.  You would think that this would have been changed at some point, but it seems that it has not been :-(

Comment: Why, out of curiosity, are you using fundamental mode?

Comment: @Dan No particular reason. Not familiar with many other modes. What do you recommend?

Comment: @Tim, two small observations: a) take into account in Emacs characters in line are counted starting from 0, not 1. b) do you need maybe a nice writing environment like olivetti https://github.com/rnkn/olivetti?

Comment: Fundamental mode is the least featureful mode available.  In virtually any case, there's a major mode that will be relevant to the file your editing (even if it's just text mode).  See the [manual node on major modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html) for more information.

Comment: @Dan I also think fundamental is the most featureless, so I don't understand why it does extra work to mix up tabs and spaces and implicitly replace each other, instead of leaving them alone.

Answer (score 7):

Like most things in emacs, the tabs policy is configurable. It sounds to me that you'd like to follow the most common apporach and use the tab key as an indentation tool and not have tab characters in your files at all.

First, you should set `(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)` early on in your emacs config. To convert existing files, emacs comes with functions `tabify` and `untabify`. See the [No Tabs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NoTabs) wiki page for more.

Secondly, the exact tab behaviour depends on emacs modes. Major modes usually have defaults and ways to change the indentation behviour. You really should use a mode tailored for the syntax you are writing. If such one does not exist yet, setting the tab policy is the way to start one. The fundamental mode is very basic by design and should be left as it is.

Answer (score 5):

To make tabs and spaces visible, you can enable `whitespace-mode` with `M-x whitespace-mode RET` or `M-x global-whitespace-mode RET`.  Have a look at variable `whitespace-style` (e.g. `M-x customize RET whitespace-style RET`).

As you found, `indent-rigidly` (which you're running with `C-x TAB`) indents with both tabs and spaces.  It will use tabs as much as possible and then make up the rest of the needed indentation with spaces.  If you want to prevent use of tabs you can set `indent-tabs-mode` nil (e.g. with `M-x set-variable RET indent-tabs-mode RET nil RET`, or see e.g. [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12173/confusion-by-the-usage-of-indent-tabs-mode-nil) for how to set it in your emacs configuration).

Comment: `indent-tabs-mode` is buffer-local, so maybe show how to set the *default* value as well.

Comment: @phils done by referring to another question