# Tex indentation with TAB

Tags: latex, tabs, syntax-table, tex

Recently, when editing files in LaTex, upon pressing TAB, I get a huge indentation. Instead, the default behavior used to be to align with respect to previous environment definition. :

I start with this (Example 1):

```
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
F = ma
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Upon pressing TAB in the second row I get something like (Example 2):

```
\begin{align}
                                 \begin{split}
F = ma
\end{split}
\end{align}
```

Whereas I would like to just smash the TAB button to get (Example 3):

```
\begin{align}
   \begin{split}
     F = ma
   \end{split}
\end{align}
```

Example 3 is what ***used to be the case*** but I might have broken something and I don't know what. Now I get Example 2. Also, if I hit the TAB outside of the align environment, I get a huge (12 spaces) displacement, which is also bizarre (previously it wouldn't do that).

I tried adding the following suggestions into my .emacs file:

1. Suggestion in the question and first answer of [Confusion by the usage of indent-tabs-mode nil](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12173/confusion-by-the-usage-of-indent-tabs-mode-nil)
2. The suggestion in [Why is emacs indenting with tabs even though indent-tabs-mode is nil?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24424/why-is-emacs-indenting-with-tabs-even-though-indent-tabs-mode-is-nil)

Comment: Specify your Emacs release. And if before you had the problem, specify that Emacs release as well. Thx.

Comment: Also state what exact mode you are using. There are several (La)TeX modes. At least the vanilla one and the one with AUCTeX.

Comment: @vonbrand Your suggestion made me switch back to LaTex mode (I was in Tex mode)! I did not know about these! Thanks!!! I'll edit the question but feel free to answer it yourself if you want the vote.

Comment: Please either delete your question or post your answer really as answer that you accept as soon as this is possible. (That keeps the overview page clean.)

Comment: @vonbrand any suggestion on how to make latex-mode the default for tex files?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I somehow managed to switch to Tex mode, instead of LaTex mode. Changing to LaTex mode is easy: M-x latex-mode. Many thanks to @vonbrand for telling me to check the mode!